# MySql Find maching records from

Tags: mysql

I'm not so good in MySql but I'm using it in my project and having a problem to perform a specific task.

I have 2 table in my database:

1. students with columns: name,... and so on
   This table has records of all active students.
2. student_logs with columns: name, date
   This table has many entries of the students and the dates from years ago that 
   includes students that are already not active.

In the final result, i want to find students that are not active for a few weeks (their max arrivalDate is few week ago).

I'm using this command:

```
SELECT   name_and_family, max(dateArrival)
FROM     **students_log**
GROUP BY name_and_family    
order by dateArrival asc;
```

In this step, I'm receiving the last date of the student's entry but it includes non-active students.

I don't know how to cross between the students so I can eliminate the non-active names form the students_log table and to get only the records with names from the **student_log** that appear only in the names from **students** table.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: how to get student are deactive ? for example if they date in  students_log is  more than 6 months ?

Comment: You would need a JOIN statement (something like JOIN students ON students.id = student.log.id) right after your FROM students_log, then add a WHERE status='active' (or whatever you have in your table) right after that. If you can post the table schema, I can give you a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

> to get only the records with names from the student_log that appear
>   only in the names from students table.

`JOIN` the two tables on `name`:

```
SELECT l.name_and_family, max(l.dateArrival)
FROM students as s
INNER JOIN students_log as l ON s.name = l.name
GROUP BY l.name_and_family
order by l.dateArrival asc;
```